# Scrollbar styling mysteriously changed

Tags: css, html

For some reason, the styling of my scrollbars changed.

I did not change any of the overflow styling (I am using `overflow-y: scroll` for my divs).

The scrollbar used to disappear when the div was not being scrolled, similar to the scrollbars used in the Facebook chat.

Now it has this static border and the scroll bar does not disappear:

[image]

I am using Chrome as my browser.

Comment: Please read our [ask] page to help you improve your question.   More specifically, refer to the section on how to create a [mcve] - great questions tend to get quick and great answers

Comment: i think this is the default browser scroll bar -_-

Comment: you can use some javascript to do some tricks....

Answer (score 1):

You can some some javascript which detects when user scroll then show scroll bar

here is a snippet

```js
function scroll(e){
e.target.style.overflow='scroll';
}
function noscroll(e){
e.target.style.overflow='hidden';
}
document.getElementById('div').onwheel=scroll;
document.getElementById('div').onmouseout=noscroll;
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line
This is a line

</div>
```

Comment: note user it is a mousewheel event not a scroll window event and scrollbar shows on div when wheel event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scroll bar to appear only when there is something to scroll in, use `overflow: auto` instead of `overflow: scroll`

Comment: Do you know of any way to get a scrollbar that disappears when the user isn't scrolling?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that without creating a custom scrollbar since all default scrollbars are browser specific

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom scroll pane. Then it is easy to set the opacity of the scrollbar to zero when the mouse leaves it, something like

```
scrollpane.onwheel = function(){
    scrollbar.style.opacity = 1;
};
scrollpane.onmouseout = function(){
    scrollbar.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Another way would be to hide the scrollbar with another element **on top of it**. You can create an outer div with `overflow:hidden` and an inner div with `overflow:scroll`. Then set absolute sizes for both divs and make the inner div about 20px bigger than the outer div. This should hide the scrollbar.

I'd like to add that it's hard to answer such a vague question. It would have been easier if you wrote your code into your question.

**EDIT:**

I have created a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aloso/r1poctgz/1/) with a **custom scrollbar**.

Custom scrollbars are a bit difficult because many events are involved, and they work differently in different browsers. For example, it might not work well on mobile devices. I have disabled text selection during dragging the slider, but this doesn't work the same on all browsers.

I even managed to **prevent scrolling on the page while the cursor is in the custom scroll pane**.

I hope that this meets your expectations!

*Aloso*